# Fix figure size when using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to fix figure size when using matplotlib. However, it never works.

The following codes should produce a figure of size 9 cm in width and 7 cm in height. However, when saving figure using savefig, figure size changes. However to fix this?

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]

y = [6,  7,  8,  9,  10, 11, 12, 13]

figw, figh = 9 / 2.54, 7 / 2.54

plt.figure(figsize=(figw, figh)) 

plt.plot(x, y, 'r-o', label='Legend')

plt.xlabel('X Lable')

plt.ylabel('Y Label')

plt.legend(loc=(0.05, 0.83))

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()

plt.savefig(fname='fig.png', dpi=600, quality=95, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
```

Comment: Research what `bbox_inches='tight'` does.

Comment: Side note, from the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html) that `quality` is "applicable only if format is jpg or jpeg, ignored otherwise."

Comment: @BigBen it seems that it is bbox_inches='tight' causes. However, without using bbox_inches='tight', there is white space in the figures. any way to remove the white space?